# apache get environment variable value

Tags: apache-2.4, environment-variables

I would like to get the value of a environment variable and assign it to another variable in Apache.

For example, get the value of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` assign it to `$_SERVER['USER-IP']` and override `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to `127.0.0.1`

I am stuck on getting the value of REMOTE_ADDR

```
<IfDefine !USER-IP>
  SetEnv USER-IP %{REMOTE_ADDR}
  SetEnv REMOTE_ADDR '127.0.0.1'
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: The IfDefine is wrong here. IfDefine tests server parameters set on the command line, not environment variables. See the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifdefine). You want If instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the docs, the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` var is not strictly an environment variable, but a cgi request meta-variable provided by the web server to the cgi context; http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875.html

> Meta-variables contain data about the request passed from the server
>      to the script

```
  meta-variable-name = "AUTH_TYPE" | "CONTENT_LENGTH" |
                       "CONTENT_TYPE" | "GATEWAY_INTERFACE" |
                       "PATH_INFO" | "PATH_TRANSLATED" |
                       "QUERY_STRING" | "REMOTE_ADDR" |
                       "REMOTE_HOST" | "REMOTE_IDENT" |
                       "REMOTE_USER" | "REQUEST_METHOD" |
                       "SCRIPT_NAME" | "SERVER_NAME" |
                       "SERVER_PORT" | "SERVER_PROTOCOL" |
                       "SERVER_SOFTWARE" | scheme |
```

The apache docs indicate that these variables cannot be overriden using the standard `SetEnv`style directives

> **Some Caveats**
>
> It is not possible to override or change the standard CGI variables using the environment manipulation directives.
>      https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html#setting

So I think it's unlikely you can set those values easily from apache conf

### Setting environment variables

(from existing server variables)

```
<Directory /var/www/server111>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    # This syntax works, as you can see from the image below...
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=USER-IP:%{REMOTE_ADDR}]

    # none of these syntax seem to work
    SetEnv USERIP %{REMOTE_ADDR}
    SetEnv USERIP2 blah
    SetEnv USERIP3 ${REMOTE_ADDR}
    SetEnv USERIP6 %{ENV:REMOTE_ADDR}
</Directory>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the second part of the question is if I can get the value of the variable SetEnv USER-IP %{REMOTE_ADDR}

Comment: The only way I can see to do it is using a rewriteRule, which has access to those variables. The SetEnv didn't seem to be able to read `%{ENV}` vars at all... I've updated the answer with an example

Comment: @TomH May I ask how you got the image with the Apache Environment above?

Comment: Looks like it's a phpinfo page... https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643880/how-can-i-create-a-phpinfo.php-page

Comment: Do you know if there is a similar way to set an environment variables from existing *header* variables?  I put up [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54556399/set-apache-environmental-variable-with-header-value) on SO but from what I can tell your answer here does something very similar, using server variables instead of headers.